# Get data from the livedate list in service

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-livedata

I have an app that add,edit,and displays `Clients` in `recyclerView`. I have 2 `Fragments` , first for displaying, and second for adding clients, ofc i use `LiveData`  in my `ShareViewModel` to comunicate  between fragments.

Now i need to implement a service to periodically write my list to json file. And that's the problem because i use

`private val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()` declaration for my `ViewModel` object to communicate between fragments using activity, and i can't use this declaration in my service for some reason. And accordingly, I cannot get the current list of Clients.
I tried to use

```
 sharedViewModel =  ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
 sharedViewModel.clientList.observe(ViewModelStore(),Observer { clientsList ->
   clientsList
 })
```

But thats doesn't work. And my question is as follows - how do I keep track of actual list from my service.
I am attaching the onStartCommand() method of my service:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        sharedViewModel =  ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        sharedViewModel.clientList.observe(ViewModelStore(),Observer { clientsList ->
            clientsList
        })
        runBlocking {

            object : CountDownTimer(1000000000, 10000), ViewModelStoreOwner {
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                    var gson = Gson()
                    var jsonString = gson.toJson(sharedViewModel.clientList.value)
                    File("/storage/emulated/0/Documents/myFile.txt").printWriter().use { out ->
                        out.write(jsonString)
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d("Tick","${sharedViewModel.clientList.value}")
                }
                override fun onFinish() {
                    var gson = Gson()
                    var jsonString = gson.toJson(sharedViewModel.clientList.value)
                    File("/storage/emulated/0/Documents/myFile.txt").printWriter().use { out ->
                        out.write(jsonString)
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                override fun getViewModelStore(): ViewModelStore {
                    return ViewModelStore()
                }
            }.start()
        }
        return START_STICKY
    }
```

Comment: Could I interest you in [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics) which I feel is far more suited for this job than service.

Comment: I will be grateful